# Edit a model with all its ForeignKey related records using django inline formsets

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys, inline-formset

I have two models like below

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=256) 

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=256)
```

So i am displaying the list of author and a link to edit the author record like below

```
{% for author in authors  %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'edit_author' author.id %}"></a></p>
{% endfor %}
```

So if we want to edit only single `Author` class, then django `UpdateView` is simply enough to do so, but when a user try to edit an author, all the foreignkey records (Book records) related to this model should also be in `Edit mode`. I mean the clicked Author, and all the Book instances related to this Author with ForeignKey should also be in the edit mode `exactly` same in the `Django Admin`

I know that we can use `django inline_formsets` would be the choice, but i am really confused on how to implement it on `my site(front end)`. So can anyone please let me know how to edit the author record along with its child records in a single page on our site ?

Comment: Don't use Generic Views. They are a very attractive magical out-of-th-box do-it-all tools that are actually limited traps of unending confusing for the uninitiated django newbie

Comment: k can u please provide me an example on how achive the above scenario ?